# kill process windows using taskkill

Tags: windows, process, kill

I have a java script which is running and kills some processes according to the pid. I run a shell with command of "taskkill /F /pid " adding the pid of the process. I have a problem that sometimes those processes are not killed. altouth I run the script again.

1) How can I find out why it is not killed ?
2) * Do you know a stronger program (than taskkill) in order to kill a process ???

10X

Answer (score 2):

If you can't kill it with `taskkill /F`, you probably won't be able to kill it with any other method - short of logging off or rebooting anyway.  For some reasons why this might happen, have a look at the answers to this question:

[Why sometimes Windows cannot kill a process?](https://superuser.com/questions/121959/why-sometimes-windows-cannot-kill-a-process)

Answer (score 2):

I use APT (Advanced Process Terminator) to kill some processes that just do not die.

I allows 12 normal ways to kill a process and 2 Kernel Kill options.

Download from [here](http://www.pendriveapps.com/advanced-process-termination-kill-running-processes/)